# How to store image path of storage\app\public in laravel-5.4

Tags: database, image, laravel, file-upload, laravel-5.4

I am using **laravel-5.4** `make:auth`. In `register.blade.php` ,added one extra field **Profile picture** for user .

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('image') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <label for="image" class="col-md-4 control-label"> Profile picture</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="image" type="file" class="form-control" name="image">

            @if ($errors->has('image'))
                <span class="help-block">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('image') }}</strong>
                </span>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want to store the image path in database. Also I have executed:
 `php artisan storage:link` and the `[public/storage]` directory has been linked.

**app\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController.php:**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    if($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $image_name = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();              
        $image_path = $request->file('image')->store('public'); 
        $image = Image::make(Storage::get($image_path))->resize(320,240)->encode();
        Storage::put($image_path,$image);
        $image_path = explode('/',$image_path);
        $user->image = $image_path;
        $user->save();
    } else{
        return "No file selected";
    }

}
```

**web.php**

```
Route::post('/store', 'RegisterController@store');
Route::get('/show', 'RegisterController@show');
```

In database,in user table under image is stored as a temporary path :

> C:\xampp\tmp\phpC762.tmp.

How to store image path of `storage\app\public`.

Answer (score 2):

Change this code in your controller

```
$user->image = $image_path;
```

to

```
$user->image = Storage::url($image_name);
```

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#file-urls

Comment: It doesnt help.My store function in registercontroller.php is not even executing.

Comment: Any error? What do you get when you `dd($image_path);` ?

Comment: its not even entering into store function.I have used the existing registercontroller[app\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController.php] and defined store function there. when user register in the form[register.blade.php], the action called is-> action="{{ route('register') }}".after the user clicks submit ,it enters into registercontroller to validate user information. my question is, why the store function is not executed in the controller.Am i defining in the correct way.

Comment: Is there a named route `register` ?

Comment: Yes. Under \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:       $this->get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');                                                                                               $this->post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');

Comment: I am using existing auth controllers[make:auth] ,so writing function in their auth controllers i guess will not work. is there any thought about this?

Comment: Are you getting any validation errors? You could override the methods in the `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` trait used in `AuthController`!

Comment: wrote a small function `under C:\xampp\htdocs\lara_company\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers.php` which says                                 `    public function show()
    {
           return "hellooo";
         
    }` and it web.php:                                                                                            `Route::get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');
Route::get('show', 'Auth\RegisterController@show');`.

Comment: The output in http://localhost:8000/register/show -> "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 179:"

Comment: The named route `register` is used for `showRegistrationForm` and not to post, hence the error. You may try changing `action={{ route('register') }}` to `action = {{ action('RegisterController@register) }}`